# Хранение структур в C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Подскажите, вот есть структура, значимый тип который по всей логике должен хранится в стеке:

```
struct MyStruct
{  
}
```

Но объект ведь  можно создать и так: `MyStruct obj = new MyStruct();`. Почему такое работает? Это же не класс, а значимый тип. Или всё же возможно создать объект структуры, который хранится в куче?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

У вас, веротно, укоренился в голове один весьма распространенный миф, что типы-значения хранятся в стеке. На самом деле это далеко не всегда так. В стеке хранятся **только** параметры методов и локальные переменные этих методов (разумеется, речь именно о типах-значениях. Ссылочные типы хранятся всегда в куче). То есть, если некий класс имеет поле типа **int**, то это поле будет храниться в куче вместе со всеми прочими данными этого класса (кстати то же самое касается массивов - содержимое массива **int[]** будет также храниться в куче). Разумеется, из этого следует, что типы-значения могут храниться в куче, и происходит это куда как чаще, чем может показаться на первый взгляд.

Впрочем, информация эта, конечно, немаловажна и любопытна, но прямого отношения к вашему вопросу не имеет.

Теперь что касается собственно вопроса. Конструкция типа

```
var foo = new Foo()
```

а точнее ключевое слово new совсем не означает, что память выделяется именно в куче и именно для ссылочного типа (в отличие от C++, где **new** означает именно возврат  указателя). Тут важно помнить, что **new** - это всего лишь часть синтаксиса языка, и само по себе это слово подразумевает всего лишь выделение памяти под объект типа Foo с вызовом его конструктора, без привязки к тому, ссылочный это тип или тип-значение.

Кстати,  помимо вышесказанного в CLR есть еще один способ хранения типпов-значений в куче. Это может быть достигнуто с помощью упаковки, то есть приведения экземпляра типа-значения к ссылочному, что также подразумевает его хранение в куче. Впрочем, это отдельная и довольно обширная тема.

З.Ы. еще одна маленькая деталь, которая, впрочем, вам вряд ли пригодится - даже локальные  переменные, относящиеся к типам-значениям, могут храниться в куче, если речь идет об анонимных методах и лямбда-функциях. Хранение их в куче в этом случае  имеет смысл для реализации замыканий.

Comment: Я понял вас, спасибо за обширный ответ, но тогда обьект может хранится в стеке если значимые могут быть в куче ?

Comment: >но тогда обьект может хранится в стеке если значимые могут быть в куче ?

что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Когда создается MyStruct obj = new MyStruct(); - это помещается в стек ? Я же не применил упаковку, а значит моя структура (или обьект структуры) сохранился в стеке ?!

Comment: я же вам всё описал выше - экземпляры  типов-значений попадают в стек при условии, что они являются локальными переменными методов.

Comment: Аааа, точно, всё спасибо разобрался !!!

Comment: +1, отличный ответ.

Добавлю лишь ссылки на Эрика: [[1]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx), [[2]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx).

Comment: кстати если с английским не дружите, блог Липперта можно почитать [на русском][1] К сожалению после его ухода из MS оба эти блога перестали пополняться, но и из того что есть можно почерпнуть неало полезного. 

[1]:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruericlippert/

Answer (score -2):

```
MyStruct obj = new MyStruct();
```

Идентично записи:

```
MyStruct obj;
```

`= new(); -` выполняет создание экземпляра и помещает его автоматически в ту память которую нужно, так как в C# это решает не пользователь, а окружение .NET

Структуры могут хранится в куче в составе классов или других структур, которые, в свою очередь, в составе классов. Но при создании структуры ее адрес и данные располагаются строго в стеке. Это сделано с тех соображений, что структуры предназначены для хранения "тесно связанных данных" которые настолько тесно связаны, что их можно считать одной переменной.

Нет смысла хранить структуру в куче и потом каждый раз обращаться к каждому ее члену. Проще скопировать сразу всю структуру и обрабатывать ее оперативно в стеке. Вот почему структура копируется полностью, а не передается по ссылке и вот почему она создается сразу локально в стеке сразу в том месте где с ней нужно работать.

В С# пользователя заставляют более четко выражать свои намерения насчет типов данных.

### Типичной структурой где можно проследить "тесно связанные данные" это DateTime, Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Point3D etc.

Также есть такое мнение, что переменные которые размещены в куче - замедляют всю систему при обращении к этим данным.

Это отчасти правда:

1. Стек и куча находятся оба в оперативной памяти (не в кэше процессора) и доступ к ним осуществляется с одинаковым временем.
2. Проблема оказывается в том, что в стеке данные расположены близко друг к другу по мере вызова "подфункций из функций". А в куче они могут быть разбросаны очень далеко по своим фактическим и виртуальным адресам. Операционная система постоянно сопоставляет физические и виртуальные адреса в таблице. Эта таблица кэшируется но имеет предельный размер. Если использовать только "данные из кучи" то таблица очень быстро забивается и перезаписывается, что замедляет работу системы;
3. Так как в стеке данные расположены в порядке вызова функций - тут нет проблемы с освобождением данных. А с кучей в С# работает "Сборщик мусора", что замедляет работу программы.
4. У структур не вызывается конструктор по умолчанию (если он не вызван явно) поэтому тратится меньше ресурсов на создание переменной (например в каком-то алгоритме где происходит много созданий в единицу времени)
5. Если структура "весит" больше 16-ти байт то издержки на ее постоянное копирование не покрываются предыдущими пунктами. Кроме того, если структура столько "весит" то можно говорить о том, что врятли столько много данных "тесно связаны" и используются неотъемлемо друг от друга, что заставляет задуматься о выборе "класса" в качестве типа переменной.

---

Основные отличия между структурами и классами:

1. На структуру нельзя делать ссылку (даже через ref) при передаче в лямбда функции. Все потому что лямбда функции (они же делегаты) используются, в том числе, для исполнения в других потоках. У других потоков свой стек и они не могут контролировать сохранность ссылок на структуры из стека других потоков.
2. Именно поэтому структуры не участвуют в блокировках, семафорах и так далее (не могут быть использованы в качестве lock) и поэтому им не нужно хранить состояние блокировки. То что называется боксингом - это перемещение структуры в кучу и добавление ей дополнительной переменной для хранения состояния блокировки (ведь в друг к ней обратятся сразу несколько потоков, а вам это не понравится).

Напрямую структура не может иметь такую переменную, поэтому происходит преобразование (боксинг), если она помешается в кучу КАК САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНЫЙ ОБЪЕКТ (тобишь class Object или любой другой класс или интерфейс который она наследует/реализует). Такое происходит каждый раз если код обращается к структуре как к Object или другому классу или интерфейсу который она наследует/реализует.

Когда структура помещается в стек в виде поля другого класса/структуры - то боксинга не происходит и просто копируются все поля структуры в кучу.

---

Comment: как связан вызов конструктора по умолчанию с местом хранения структуры?

Comment: >>>Но объект ведь можно создать и так: MyStruct obj = new MyStruct();. Почему такое работает? Это же не класс, а значимый тип.<<<

Comment: Программисты не используют структуры, потому что обычно требуется более широкий функционал, чем есть у структур, программисты привыкли писать классы и продолжают это делать.

Comment: Как скажешь, шєф

Comment: Вы лучше выпилите из ответа всякие панибратские слова и прочее такое. Я минус не ставил, но люди то ставят. Может вы там по сути и правы в чём-то, но качество ответа из-за орфографических ошибок, "простецких" слов, и вашего личного мнения по каким-то вопросам - оно ведь страдает.

Comment: Вы и сами можете подредактировать - я безграмотный тупой начинающий программист, но как оказалось - в жизни это не главное