# Где хранятся переменные класса

Tags: c#, ооп

Класс ведь ссылочный тип, а переменные в классе могут быть типами по значению. Например:

```
class Car
{
    public int maxSpeed;       
    public Car(int max)
    {
       maxSpeed = max;
    }
}
```

Где хранится `maxSpeed` — в стеке или куче?

Comment: а ваши какие предположения?

Comment: в куче, как вы представляете себе расположение в стеке?

Comment: @Etki, класс в куче в поле в стеке:-D

Comment: вообще вот [ответ Эрика Липперта](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565331/fields-of-class-are-they-stored-in-the-stack-or-heap) на аналогичный вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос о структуре в C# !](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/278178/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: @Arhad там вопрос другой. просто ответ частично подходит :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 16):

Сам по себе вопрос вызван двумя проблемами

- достаточно распространенным, но в общем случае неверным утверждением "переменные value-type хранятся в стеке"
- небольшой путаницей в терминологии - поля класса это не "переменные" - не локальные переменные.

Дело в том, что на уровне языка C# нет понятия "стэк" и "куча". Есть два вида типов:

- Ссылочные. Значение переменной или поля класса этого типа хранит в себе адрес памяти, по которому лежит экземпляр типа. Сам по себе экземпляр при этом обычно лежит в куче. Пример - строки.
- Value-types (типы-значения). Значение переменной или поля класса хранит значение напрямую. Пример - int.

Понятие стека есть на уровне .NET/IL. Локальные переменные в методах уровня IL .NET хранятся в стеке. Переменная C# превращается в переменную метода IL далеко не всегда. Это происходит, если:

- на нее нет замыканий
- она объявлена в не-async-методе
- еще много разных условий, вызванных особенностями реализации конкретного компилятора C#.

Поля типов хранятся как часть самого экземпляра типа. Они физически лежат в том куске памяти, который выделен под конкретных экземпляр типа. Т.е. если экземпляр сам по себе лежит в стеке (например, это экземпляр структуры) - то поле хранится в стеке. Если экземпляр лежит в куче - то и поле лежит в куче.

Конкретные примеры

- В методе объявлен `int a` - он лежит прямо в стеке
- В методе объявлен `string s` - в переменной в стеке лежит адрес строки в куче.
- В методе объявлен `Car c` - в переменной в стеке лежит адрес объекта Car. Сам объект лежит в куче. Частью объекта в куче является поле maxSpeed, в нем лежит значение скорости.
- В методе объявлен `int [] arr` - в переменной в стеке лежит адрес массива в куче. Прямо в объекте массива в куче лежат значения отдельных ячеек.
- Объявлена структура `Point` с полями `X`/`Y`. В методе объявлена переменная `Point p` - в переменной в стеке лежит сама структура, со всеми полями.

Comment: по последнему пункту вопрос насчет структуры: Объявлена структура Point с полями X/Y, если в методе изменить значение полей, почему они не изменяться по факту, а только в самом методе?

Comment: @user210691 потому что структура - это value type, в метод передается копия структуры, а не ссылка на оригинал. точно так же не меняются снаружи, например, переменные типа int, переданные в метод.

Comment: можете подсказать еще один момент: а если в структуре указан ссылочный тип - напр. экземпляр класса, то он где в куче получается? (создается ссылка в стеке на объект в куче, если я верно понял?) Спасибо!

Comment: @user210691 да, правильно

Answer (score 6):

Перевод [ответа на аналогичного вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565331/fields-of-class-are-they-stored-in-the-stack-or-heap)

Типы-значения называются "типы-значения", потому что копируются по значению. Ссылочные типы называются "ссылочными типами", потому что копируются по ссылке. Это не совсем верно, что "типы-значения всегда находятся на стеке". Если бы это было правдой они бы назывались "Типы стека"(stack types) и "Типы кучи"(heap types).

Правда в том, что все зависит от деталей реализации. Различные реализации фреймворков могут выбирать использовать им стек или кучу, так как они хотят. Ниже пример как это реализовано у Микрософта:

- значение переменной ссылочного типа указывает на значение в куче. Ссылки в основном 32-х или 64-х битное целое.
- значение переменной значимого типа - это само значение.
- значения локальных переменных хранятся на стеке, пока эти переменные не в блоке итератора, или не замкнуты в анонимном методе или лямбда-выражении. В этих случаях значения локальных переменных хранятся в куче. Конечно, пока эти переменные не выкинуты оптимизатором, в этом случае они нигде не хранятся. Или, возможно они могут быть перенесены в регистры и в этом случае они не будут ни на стеке, ни в куче.
- значения экземпляров ссылочных типов и статические переменные хранятся в куче.

`maxSpeed` - это поле, следовательно, хранится в куче.

Единственная вещь идущая в стек - это локальные переменные (и временные переменные сгенерированные компилятором), которые не замкнуты в лямбда функциях или анонимных методах, и не находятся в блоке итератора. И, конечно, jitter может не использовать стек, а сложить все в регистры, если достаточно свободных регистров.

Но, на самом деле, я должен спросить: почему вы беспокоитесь о том, что пойдет в стек, а что в кучу? В стек идет только то, что мы можем быстро положить в него, все остальное идет в кучу.

Comment: хочу разобраться для себя, теперь ясно - спасибо!

Comment: @user210691, вопросы в конце это тоже часть перевода :-D они присутствуют и в оригинальном ответе Эрика Липперта

Answer (score 2):

Объекты класса хранятся в куче. А что представляет собой экземпляр класса? По-сути, тип да набор своих переменных.

А в стеке хранятся те переменные, которые объявляются внутри функций/методов. Отсюда и проблема переполнения стека при чрезмерном рекурсивном вызове функций (см. название сайта `:)`).