# Скорость выполнения при передаче ссылки на объект

Tags: c#

Добрый день!
Прошу Вас подсказать мне.
Вопрос: какой код будет выполняться быстрее и почему? 
Или разницы в скорости не будет, т.к передается ссылка на область в куче.

Допустим, есть некоторый тип:

```
class MyClass
{
    internal int a;
    public MyClass(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Вариант 1

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(5);
        Work(myClass.a);            
    }

    static void Work(int a)
    {
        int b = a + 5;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Вариант 2

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(5);
        Work(myClass);            
    }

    static void Work(MyClass myClass)
    {
        int b = myClass.a + 5;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: С таким примером как ваш разницы не будет никакой. Но, если бы в методе Work был бы, допустим, цикл где как в Варианте 2 в каждой итерации было бы извлечение данных по ссылке, то тогда, такой вариант бы был медленнее Варианта 1.

Comment: @K.Oleg  Чем неопытнее программист, тем больше его волнует скорость, высосанная из пальца. :)

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо, это и хотел понять!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не стыдно не знать, стыдно не учиться :) А скорость меня волнует потому что есть события количеством 1000+шт/сек которые нужно обрабатывать. И когда я дополняю код обработки большим функционалом, понимаю, что падает скорость обработки в общем, вот и спрашиваю Ваших комментариев, чтобы повысить свои навыки!

Comment: Только учтите, чтобы заметить такую разницу понадобятся циклы с миллионными количествами итераций. Потому в 99% случаев можно сказать, что это проблема не стоит и выеденного яйца.

Comment: @Bulson, понял учту, меня интересовал сам принцип, будет ли вообще разница в скорости, т.к. не до конца понимаю как работает куча, общие принципы мне ясны, а вот подробности...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все значения переменных передаются по значению:в ссылочных типах значение это ссылка, в значимых - значение.

Конкретно в вашем случае:

- пример 1 `Work(myClass.a);`  - Вы обращаетесь к куче и копируете значение из кучи, далее уже работаете с локальной переменной, которая будет храниться в стеке
- пример 2 `Work(myClass);` - Вы обращаетесь к переменной `myClass` и копируете ее значение, т.е. ссылку на область памяти, где хранится объект. В данном случае объектом является класс, поэтому и хранится он в куче. Далее в методе Вы обращаетесь уже к локальной переменной, хранящейся в куче, для извлечения адреса памяти и извлечения значения объекта.

На первый взгляд разница очевидна: передавать по значению проще, но представьте ситуацию, когда вам надо передать миллион значений, а использовать только 1. Тогда быстрее будет передать массив ссылок, чем массив значений.

Если посмотреть на Ваш случай, то разницы практически не видно, но первый метод будет работать быстрее.

О том, где хранятся переменные, можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524432/221908)

Comment: Спасибо, за подробный ответ!

Comment: @K.Oleg этот ответ будет верен только в случае, если компилятор не решит заинлайнить Work прямо в Main (т.е. скорее всего он решит так не делать, но нельзя сказать наверняка :)

Comment: @PashaPash, несомненно, чтобы сказать точно, надо проводить измерения

Answer (score 9):

Честнее всего будет ответить на ваш вопрос - "невозможно предсказать, возьмите и померяйте на реальном коде". И вот почему:

Вот IL, в который компилируются ваши примеры:

IL1:

```
Main
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.5
IL_0007:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication15.MyClass::.ctor(int32)
IL_000c:  ldfld      int32 ConsoleApplication15.MyClass::a
IL_0011:  call       void ConsoleApplication15.Program::Work(int32)

Work
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
IL_0002:  add
IL_0003:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0008:  ret
```

IL2:

```
Main
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.5
IL_0007:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication15.MyClass::.ctor(int32)
IL_000c:  call       void ConsoleApplication15.Program::Work(class ConsoleApplication15.MyClass)

Work
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldfld      int32 ConsoleApplication15.MyClass::a
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.5
IL_0007:  add
IL_0008:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_000d:  ret
```

Ок, что видно из этого кода? Компилятор уже немного оптимизировал выполнение. Например, в IL1.Main он пользуется удачным совпадением - параметры в функции передаются через стек, результат вызова конструктора также складывается в стек - а значит для передачи myClass в качестве параметра Work никаких телодвижений делать не нужно. Т.е. того, что видно в C# коде:

> Вы обращаетесь к переменной myClass и копируете ее значение, т.е. ссылку на область памяти, где хранится объект

В IL не происходит. Но все равно - явно видно, что в первом примере кода меньше. А значит можно сделать вывод, что он работает быстрее. Но на самом деле из IL выводы делать нельзя. И вот почему:

---

IL код не выполняется напрямую. Он компилируется в машинный код под конкретную платформу. А в конкретной платформе кроме стека могут использоваться и другие механизмы передачи параметров

В реальности передача параметров может происходить не через железный стек. Более того, в CLR на x86/x64 первые два параметра передаются через регистры rcx/rdx (ecx/edx). А результат из метода возвращается через rax/eax Вот во что реально компилируется ваш код на x64 (на моей машине):

ASM1:

```
Main
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(5);
00007FF8F6F20489  mov         rcx,7FF8F6E15A88h  
00007FF8F6F20493  call        00007FF956512510  
00007FF8F6F20498  mov         dword ptr [rax+8],5  
            Work(myClass.a);
00007FF8F6F2049F  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FF8F6F204A2  call        00007FF8F6F20080  

Work:
00007FF8F6F204D4  add         ecx,5  
00007FF8F6F204D7  call        00007FF954497BE0
```

ASM2:

```
Main:
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(5);
00007FF8F6EF0489  mov         rcx,7FF8F6DE5A98h  
00007FF8F6EF0493  call        00007FF956512510  
00007FF8F6EF0498  mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF8F6EF049B  mov         dword ptr [rcx+8],5  
            Work(myClass);
00007FF8F6EF04A2  call        00007FF8F6EF0088  

Work
00007FF8F6F204D4  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rcx+8]  
00007FF8F6F204D7  add         ecx,5  
00007FF8F6F204DA  call        00007FF954497BE0
```

Ок, чем это отличается от IL? Тем, что стек не используется. Совсем. Оптимизатор все запихнул в регистры.

Чем реально отличаются варианты? Одной инструкцией:

```
 00007FF8F6EF0498  mov         rcx,rax
```

mov из регистра в регистр занимает 1 такт процессора. Т.е. если какой-то из примеров и будет работать быстрее на x64 - вы этого скорее всего не заметите.

Производительность зависит от слишком многих параметров - платформы, версии JIT, типа компиляции - и невозможно учесть их все при написании кода. Не заморачивайтесь. Решайте проблемы по мере их появления.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ!