# Где выделяется память для значимых типов?

Tags: c#

Интересует, где выделяется память для значимых типов, на стеке, в куче, почему это так?

Comment: или возможно вот этот больше дубликат: [Хранение структур в C#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/278178/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, да, структуры то что надо. Закрываю :)